# Postgres/Prisma - How to reorder records or add number index field

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I am creating an application which will allow the user to reorder items in a list. These items are represented as records in a Postgres DB. I am using Prisma ORM.

My brute solution is to manually create an orderIndex field on each record. The problem is that when the field is updated in one, I will need to update the orderIndex of each other record.

Is there an easy way to change the order that records are stored? Or is there a field I can create that auto-increments a count of each record, changing each number as the others change, so there is a maintained sequence with no gaps starting from 0?

Comment: Create your `orderindex` but define it not as an integer but `numeric`. Also create a sequence, **does not have to be gapless** as you are interested only in the relative value not the actual value. When a item is moved assign the new `orderindex` as the average of the of those it is between. When selecting just `order by orderindex`.

Comment: After some thought I figured an example would be in order. However, I do not know your obscurification manager (Prisma ORM) so I cannot provide an example in it. I have perhaps the next best thing. I created a Postgres procedure which handles reassigning the 'orderindex'. Note that when a item is moved **only that single item is updated** not the entire list. It should at least give you an idea  of the approach you can take. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6DJAh4Jd).